# resize/edit multiple meshes relative to their orientation/position blender

Tags: mesh

Let's say I have three identical meshes, but some of them are rotated as shown in the image:

[image]

Now in edit mode, I want to move the face to change the size of the mesh, what are possible workflows for the mesh to resize? See the arrows I drew in the image. I want the face of the mesh move relative to its object.  I tried experimenting with parenting object, shift+G (select face by normal/coplanar) etc.

I am stuck. Hope I explained myself clear.

Comment: in the case you show, you could extrude along normals, then dissolve the edge that it has created?

Answer (score 3):

If you want your meshes to *remain* identical for a while during modelling, or permanently, but with different orientations, they could be <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> instances of one another, instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> copies of one another..

[image]

For entirely separate objects, in this case, you could set the pivot to 'Individual Origins' and the orientation to 'Normal'.

You can edit multiple meshes simultaneously, using <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to translate faces along their normals, averaged per selection-island:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be simply achieved by the following procedure:

When in edit mode, select the faces you want to extrude, and set the transform pivot point to individual origins:[image]

Now, when you extrude, you get this result:[image]

Now if you don't want the edges, you can select loops by double clicking on them and press X>Dissolve Edges.[image]

Comment: +1 .. but it doesn't need to be an extrusion followed by a dissolve.. if you don't want the extra edges, then as well as setting 'Individual Origins' you could also set the orientation to 'Normal', and use GZ on the faces.

Comment: Hmmm... I guess you're right. Anyways, thanks for the tip.